# Somar inputs se ele for preenchido com um determinado valor

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma tela de cadastro que possui 30 inputs e nele vou informar valores de 0 a 99 e tenho outro input de Total.
Preciso quê, quando determinadas quantidades de inputs for preenchidos a Quantidade de Inputs seja multiplicado por 5.
Exemplo:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero1" name="numero1" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero2" name="numero2"value="15"><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero3" name="numero3"value="20"><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero4" name="numero4" value="25"><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero5" name="numero5" value="30">
```

Percebam que entre os 30 Inputs existentes na página, tive apenas 5 preenchidos. Logo, essa quantidade será multiplicado por 5 mostrando o calculo no Input TOTAL.

```html
<label>Total: </label><input type="total" class="form-control" id="total" name="total">
```

Comment: Desculpe mas sua pergunta e explicação não estão claras o suficiente para entender o que pretende.

Comment: Léo preciso que o cálculo seja feito de acordo com a quantidade de Campos (inputs) preenchidos e não pelo valor contido em cada um deles E que essa quantidade seja multiplicado por R$: 5,00

Comment: No caso, vc quer que o valor do total, seja 25?
No caso 5 inputs preenchidos multiplicado por 5. Seria isso?

Comment: Exatamente, Rebeca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque dentro de uma `<div id="divInputs">` somente  os inputs necessários a questão, ou seja os 30.

Em cada input o evento onBlur que ocorre (no caso aciona a função javascript) quando um objeto perde o foco `onblur="quantComValue()"` Você pode escolher outro evento que se encaixe melhor as suas necessidades

```js
function quantComValue(){

// Obtenha o div que você deseja examinar.
var div = document.getElementById("divInputs");

// Obtem todos os inputs dentro do seu div
var inputs = div.getElementsByTagName('input');

// Obtem o número de inputs encontrados
var totalInputs = inputs.length;

// Percorra-os e verifique qual deles tem um valor.
var inputsComValue = 0;
for(var i=0; i<totalInputs; i++)
    if(inputs[i].value!=='')
        inputsComValue +=1;   
        
/*Caso queira preencher o total a partir de 
determinado numero de inputs preenchidos
utilize um if informando o valor, ex: >2 */

if (inputsComValue>2){

     document.getElementById('total').value = inputsComValue*5;
     
}

}
```

```html
<div id="divInputs">
<input onblur="quantComValue()" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero1" name="numero1" value=""><br>
<input onblur="quantComValue()" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero2" name="numero2"value=""><br>
<input onblur="quantComValue()" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero3" name="numero3"value=""><br>
<input onblur="quantComValue()" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero4" name="numero4" value=""><br>
<input onblur="quantComValue()" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero5" name="numero5" value=""><br>
<input onblur="quantComValue()" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero6" name="numero6" value=""><br>

</div>
<input type="total" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" placeholder="total">
```

Comment: Leo, muito obrigado.
Era exatamente isso que eu precisava.